# Spartan 3ADSP device DNA read via JTAG

Tags: vhdl, fpga

how to read device DNA for Spartan 3A DSP via JTAG cable using iMPACT tool ? and if any other methods available to cross check the code readead deviceDNA value, whether it is correct deviceDNA value of that device OR not?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Xilinx AR for this:

[AR# 40856 iMPACT- How can I read DNA from my FPGA with IMPACT?](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/40856.html)

> For Spartan-3A series devices (Spartan-3A, Spartan-3AN
>   andSpartan-3ANDSP)
>
> ```
>     To read if the DNA iMPACT batch mode command is available. ("readDna -p <position>") How to get the Xilinx Device DNA via iMPACT
> ```
>
> batch mode?
>   1. Generate iMPACT batch mode file say ".cmd" (in any ASCII text Editor) with following text commands in it. You can run this in
>   iMPACT batch mode. In the commands below, "X" denotes the position of
>   the targeted device.
>
> ```
>     setMode -bs
>     setCable -port auto
>     Identify
>     identifyMPM
>     Readdna -p X
>     exit
> ```
>
> 2.Run above generated file "readDNA.cmd" (ASCII text file) in IMPACT batch mode command line as:
>
> ```
>     Impact -batch <filename>.cmd
>     The above command will display the DNA number on the DOS command console.
>     Note: If FPGA is configured prior to read Device DNA via JTAG port then the value will be wrong. Please make sure that FPGA is not
> ```
>
> configured from external Flash or JTAG device. To achieve this simply
>   change mode pins or erase the external Flash deviceand powercycle the
>   board.

Comment: To use this method, I can read the DNA value but it was changed in each & every read, and my FPGA is fresh one not to programmed yet.Can plz explain why its happen ?. and how to find which DNA value is correct one ?.

Comment: Well, it was a long time ago I did this, I will see if I can do this on my board, I don't have any Spartan based devices, but I can test it on Virtex 5, 6 or Zynq and see if I can get it to work.